# Scroll bars foul up mouse hovering events for overlapping fixed position elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm maintaining an application that has a custom dropdown menu the supports submenus that expand to the right. When a list of options grows long enough, a scroll bar is introduced to allow you to scroll through additional options. Both the parent menu and sub-menus use fixed positioning, and this seems to be the crux of the problem.

The problem is that, for the purpose of `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, the scroll bar is always on top. As you move your mouse to the right to an item in the sub-menu, once your mouse is over the scroll bar, the `mouseleave` event fires even though the sub-menu is on top of the scroll bar. And once you move your mouse off of the scroll bar (but still on top of the sub-menu item) the `mouseenter` and `mouseover` events fire for that sub-menu item.

https://jsfiddle.net/01pjnfac/1/

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const fixedContainer = document.getElementById('fixed-container');

fixedContainer.onmouseenter = () => output.innerHTML = 'Entered parent<br />' + output.innerHTML;
fixedContainer.onmouseleave = () => output.innerHTML = 'Left parent<br />' + output.innerHTML;

const fixedChild = document.getElementById('fixed-child');

fixedChild.onmouseenter = () => output.innerHTML = 'Entered child<br />' + output.innerHTML;
fixedChild.onmouseleave = () => output.innerHTML = 'Left child<br />' + output.innerHTML;
```

```css
div {
  border: thick solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

#fixed-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1vh;
  left: 1vw;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#fixed-child {
  position: fixed;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vh;
  left: 40vw;
  top: 25vh;
}

#output {
  margin-top: 54vh;
  border: thin solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed-container">
  <div id="fixed-child">

  </div>
</div>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

What's even more strange is that if you call `document.elementsFromPoint()` in the `mouseleave` event, the sub-menu and sub-list-item appear in the results. So the browser knows that the mouse is still hovering over the sub-menu, but dispatches the `mouseleave` event anyway.

On top of that, the scroll bar also prevents you from clicking on the sub-menu item. Clicking and dragging allows you to scroll up and down even though your mouse is hovering over a child element that is on top of the scroll bar.

Is this a known bug? I can fix it by changing the menu to use absolute instead of fixed positioning, but I would expect the browser to be smart enough to recognized when a fixed position element is on top of a scroll bar of another element.

Comment: In which user agents are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: @esqew Good question. So far, Chrome and Edge. I haven't tried it in any other browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @ths. I forgot that SO has its own snippet functionality now.